# Writing a program in C++ that asks the user to enter values for all primitive types in C++

Tags: c++

I am starting to learn C++ and I am trying to create a program that asks the user to add values for all primitive types in C++, here is what I have written so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 bool empty_bool;
 char empty_char;
 int empty_int;
 float empty_float;
 double empty_double;
 cout << "Please enter a value for all inbuilt primitive types in C++" << endl;
 cout << "Boolean:";
 cin >> empty_bool;
 cout << "Char";
 cin >> empty_char;
 cout << "Int";
 cin >> empty_int;
 cout << "float";
 cin >> empty_float;
 cout << "double";
 cin >> empty_double;
}
```

The problem is that my program takes the input of boolean but then it just prints the rest of the variable names but it doesn't allow to take the value for the said variable and I can't figure out why, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you write something like `true` as input for the boolean? That is not going to work. You need to input `0` (for false) or `1` (for true).

Comment: What do you enter for Boolean? Unless `boolalpha` flag is set (and by default it is not), `cin >> empty_bool` expects an integer in the input, and interprets zero as `false` and non-zero as `true`

Comment: In C++ bool is internally an integral value. So you have to enter 1 for true and 0 for false.

Comment: Yes I entered true, instead of 1 or 0, coming from a JavaScript background I didn't thought about that, thanks!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik My GCC accepts only `0` and `1`, no other numbers as input for `bool` (with `std::noboolalpha`)

Comment: @uneven_mark Of course. `std::noboolalpha` turns `boolalpha` flag off (hence "no" in front).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I was referring to your comment "*expects an integer in the input*" and "*and non-zero as true*". It seems to accept only `0` and `1`, no other integers.

Comment: @uneven_mark Ah. Indeed, only 0 and 1 should be accepted, anything else sets `failbit`.

Answer (score 1):

After doing any input, `cin` will contain a result condition. Reading invalid input will put the input stream `cin` into a `fail` state; typically, you are supposed to check that by evaluating `cin` in a boolean context:

```
if (cin >> empty_int)
    cout << empty_int; // empty_int here is not empty anymore
else
    cout << "error";
```

When reading an inappropriately formatted value for `bool` (as mentioned in comments, it must be 0 or 1 or `true` or `false` depending on the `boolalpha` flag), `cin` remembers its error state, and will not do any further input [until it is reset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17012466/509868):

```
cin.clear();
```

---

Note by user4581301:

Note that `clear` does not remove the offending data from the stream. Depending on what was read and how before the failure, you probably have something in the stream that will cause the exact same error again. If so, remove it before continuing, using one of the following ideas:

- use `std::istream::ignore` (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18348452/509868))
- read it into something permissive like a `std::string`
- or whatever best fits your usage